# How to add auth user id or session to logging in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, monolog

## My Goal

I'm willing to add the current authenticated user id to log lines (I'm using syslog driver) as a custom log formatting.

As part of my research, I've seen there are nice packages and [tutorials](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/custom-user-log-activity-in-laravel-5-app-exampleexample.html) to log user activity to database. But at least for now my intention is to move forward without extra packages and logging to *syslog* as I'm currently doing.

A typical log call in my app would look like:

```
logger()->info("Listing all items");
```

I could also do something like:

```
$uid = Auth::id();
logger()->info("Listing all items for {$uid}");
```

It would be similar to what a documentation example suggests:

[image: Docs Example]

I'm currently doing this for certain lines, but since I'd like to have it in all log calls it would become like repeating myself every time I log something.

## Desired Output

Current:

```
Dec 10 23:54:05 trinsic Laravel[13606]: local.INFO: Hello world []
```

Desired:

```
Dec 10 23:54:05 trinsic Laravel[13606]: local.INFO [AUTH_USER_ID=2452]: Hello world []
```

## My Approach

I have tried to *tap* the logger with success on changing the format, [as suggested on docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#advanced-monolog-channel-customization).

But my current problem is that at the point the `CustomizeFormatter` class is excecuted, the Auth id seems not to be resolved just yet (not sure about this, but `dd()` returns null, so that's my guess):

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class CustomizeFormatter
{
    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        $authUser = Auth::id(); // null

        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            $formatter = new LineFormatter("%channel%.%level_name% [AUTH={$authUser}]: %message% %extra%");
            $handler->setFormatter($formatter);
        }
    }
}
```

## Setup

Laravel 5.7
Log Driver: `syslog`

```
    // config/logging.php

    'syslog' => [
        'driver' => 'syslog',
        'tap' => [ App\Logging\CustomizeFormatter::class ],
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],
```

## My Question(s)

- Is there any way to resolve the auth user at this point, or any other approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer of *DigitalDrifter* and part of [this post from Emir Karşıyakalı](https://emirkarsiyakali.com/quick-tip-logging-mastery-with-laravel-7282988032a7) I managed to get a fair enough solution.

I could not grab the User ID since (as per my understanding at this point) it can't be resolved just yet. But I felt satisfied with getting a more or less accurate client id and session id, so I can trace a user interaction thread on logs:

```
<?php

namespace App\Loggers;

use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class LocalLogger
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            $handler->setFormatter($this->getLogFormatter());
        }
    }

    protected function getLogFormatter()
    {
        $uniqueClientId = $this->getUniqueClientId();

        $format = str_replace(
            '[%datetime%] ',
            sprintf('[%%datetime%%] %s ', $uniqueClientId),
            LineFormatter::SIMPLE_FORMAT
        );

        return new LineFormatter($format, null, true, true);
    }

    protected function getUniqueClientId()
    {
        $clientId = md5($this->request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT').'/'.$this->request->ip());
        $sessionId = \Session::getId();

        return "[{$clientId}:{$sessionId}]";
    }
}
```

Config:

```
    // config/logger.php

    'syslog' => [
        'driver' => 'syslog',
        'level'  => 'debug',
        'tap'    => [App\Loggers\LocalLogger::class],
    ],
```

## Result

Now I can get something like:

```
Dec 11 13:54:13 trinsic Fimedi[13390]: [2018-12-11 16:54:13] c6c6cb03fafd4b31493478e76b490650 local.INFO: Hello world
```

or

```
Dec 11 13:55:44 trinsic Fimedi[13390]: [2018-12-11 16:55:44] [c6c6cb03fafd4b31493478e76b490650:xUs2WxIb3TvKcpCpFNPFyvBChE88Nk0YbwZI3KrY] local.INFO: Hello world
```

Depending on how I calculate the user/session ids.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the request object as a constructor arg to your custom formatter class, then access the user from there:

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class CustomizeFormatter
{
    public $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        $authUser = $this->request->user();
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            $formatter = new LineFormatter("%channel%.%level_name% [AUTH={$authUser->id}]: %message% %extra%");
            $handler->setFormatter($formatter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @DigitalDrifter. It makes a lot of sense in order to get Laravel to resolve the request object and access the auth user from there, and we seem to get closer to the problem. However despite the request object is accessible, the user (`$this->request->user()`) is returning null. (I'm making sure that I'm logged in, so it's not that I run from console or such).

Comment: [Here](https://prnt.sc/ltcvus) a `dd($this->request)` right into `__invoke($logger)`. I suspect this is because `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,` is run much after logging is configured? But really not sure on this.

Comment: If you `dd($this->request->user());` right after the assignment in the constructor, what is the output?

Comment: Right after the assignment in the constructor, or right after retrieving on __invoke, it returns `null` in both cases.

Comment: Another possible option is extending or wrapping around Illuminate\Log\Logger and resolve and append the auth user id at that point.